# Grails - override a bean property value in resources.groovy

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

There's a `messageSource` bean defined in the Grails i18n plugin [defined thusly](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-i18n/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/i18n/I18nGrailsPlugin.groovy#L71):

```
messageSource(PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource) {
  basenames = baseNames.toArray()
  fallbackToSystemLocale = false
  pluginManager = manager
  ....
}
```

Is it possible to override the configuration of just the `fallbackToSystemLocale` value from my resources.groovy, something like:

```
messageSource {
    fallbackToSystemLocale = true
}
```

The above doesn't work, I get an error: "Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Bean definition is abstract"

Comment: I don't know if you can do that, but you can use the setter: `messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any reason not to simply update the bean in `BootStrap.groovy`?

```
class BootStrap {
    def def messageSource
    def init = { servletContext ->
        messageSource.fallbackToSystemLocale = true
    }
}
```

If you want to modify beans before BootStrap has run, you can use a `BeanPostProcessor` as in [this blog post](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/overriding-properties-in-a-spring-bean-with-beanfactorypostprocessor/).

src/groovy/yourpkg/CustomBeanPostProcessor:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor

class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{

    @Override
    Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        return bean
    }

    @Override
    Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if(beanName == 'messageSource') {
            bean.setFallbackToSystemLocale = true
        }
        return bean
    }
}
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    customBeanPostProcessor(CustomBeanPostProcessor)
}
```

Comment: BeanPostProcessor seems a more organized approach.