# Grails App is missing the application context in links after redeploy

Tags: grails, gsp, applicationcontext

my Grails 2.3.7 application is missing its application context for links in a specific scenario. While I'm developing, all is fine. When I deploy the application to Tomcat 8 and start it with `dbCreate` in datasource as `create` or `create-drop`, all is working fine. But when I restart Tomcat (or redeploy) and have dbCreate in datasource set to `none`, links in the application are generated without the application context.
I use `<g:link controller="controller" action="action">Link Text</g:link>` to create links, in development and if using `dbCreate="create"` links are generated as `/application/controller/action` but when using `dbCreate="none"` after a restart links are generated as `/controller/action`, the `application` part is missing and thus the target of the link can not be found. For assets like css files, the ressource links are generated correctly, including the `application` part.
I tried to set `grails.app.context`and `grails.serverURL` in Config.groovy, but with no success. I'd be grateful for any hint on solving this problem.
(Searching on SO just returns questions with the opposite direction, where people ask how to omit the application part in the link, this is not what I want.)

Update: Doesn't seem to be related to tomcat, I have the same behaviour when running with `grails run-app`.

Update: I can reproduce this with `run-app`, `prod run-app` and also with deployed wars, but the error doesn't happen everytime, maybe during 2 of 3 starts of the web-app, so I guess it could be a timing issue with the servlet context, but I don't know more yet.

Upadte: Debugging shows, that in `DefaultLinkGenerator` the `contextPath` equals the empty String, but should be either null or 'application'.

Update: The grails bean `grailsLinkCreator` is instantiated correctly during app startup. This beans is implemented in `CachingLinkGenerator` which calls its superclass `DefaultLinkGenerator`. Sometime during startup, but after the creation and initialization of this bean, the variable `contextPath` in `DefaultLinkGenerator` is set to the empty String, but I don't know when, from where and why.

Answer (score -1):

I still can't fix (or find) the reason why this happens, but I found a workaround here on SO: [Grails - override a bean property value in resources.groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063391/grails-override-a-bean-property-value-in-resources-groovy)

The relevant part is:

> If you want to modify beans before BootStrap has run, you can use a
>   BeanPostProcessor [...]
>
> src/groovy/yourpkg/CustomBeanPostProcessor:
>
> ```
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor
>
> class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{
>
>     @Override
>     Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
>         return bean
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
>         if(beanName == 'messageSource') {
>             bean.setFallbackToSystemLocale = true
>         }
>         return bean
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> resources.groovy:
>
> ```
> beans = {
>     customBeanPostProcessor(CustomBeanPostProcessor)
> }
> ```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @FrankerZ I edited my answer according to your suggestion, thanks for the hint.